# secuesocial 3.0-M1 on play2.1.0?

Tags: java, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I've been using play 2.1.0 for a while and I've been having trouble looking for  a way to get `securesocial` to work. I tried different versions, even downloaded the latest `typesafe` activator to try to use it with play2.4 but no luck.

Does anyone know if can I use `securesocial` 3.0-M1 with play 2.1.0?

my controllers\application.java

package controllers;

import play.Logger;

import play.libs.F;

import play.mvc.Controller;

import play.mvc.Result;

import securesocial.core.BasicProfile;

import securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment;

import securesocial.core.java.SecureSocial;

import securesocial.core.java.SecuredAction;

import securesocial.core.java.UserAwareAction;w

import service.DemoUser;

import views.html.index;

import views.html.linkResult;

public class Application extends Controller {

```
public static Logger.ALogger logger =
```

Logger.of("application.controllers.Application");

```
private RuntimeEnvironment env;



public Application(RuntimeEnvironment env) {



        this.env = env;



    }




public Result index() {




    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){




        logger.debug("access granted to index




    DemoUser user = (DemoUser) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);




    return ok(index.render(user, SecureSocial.<DemoUser>env()));




}




@UserAwareAction




public Result userAware()
```

{

```
    DemoUser demoUser = (DemoUser) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);



    String userName ;   




    if ( demoUser != null ) {   




        BasicProfile user = demoUser.main;  




        if ( user.firstName().isDefined() ) {   




            userName = user.firstName().get();  




        } else if ( user.fullName().isDefined()) {  




            userName = user.fullName().get();   




        } else {    




            userName = "authenticated user";    




        }   




    } else {    



        userName = "guest"; 



    }   




    return ok("Hello " + userName + ", you are seeing a public page");  




}
```

@SecuredAction(authorization = WithProvider.class, params = {"twitter"})

```
public Result onlyTwitter() {   




    return ok("You are seeing this because you logged in using Twitter");   



}
```

@SecuredAction

```
public Result linkResult() {    




    DemoUser current = (DemoUser) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY  




}
```

public F.Promise currentUser() {

```
   return SecureSocial.currentUser(env).map( new F.Function<Object, Result>() { 


        @Override   



        public Result apply(Object maybeUser) throws Throwable {    



            String id;  




            if ( maybeUser != null ) {  




                DemoUser user = (DemoUser) maybeUser;   




                id = user.main.userId();    




            } else {    




                id = "not available. Please log in.";




            }   




            return ok("your id is " + id);  

        }


    }); 

}
```

}

my routes

## Home page

GET        /                    @controllers.Application.index

GET        /userAware           @controllers.Application.userAware

GET        /only-twitter        @controllers.Application.onlyTwitter

GET        /link-result         @controllers.Application.linkResult

GET        /current-user        @controllers.Application.currentUser

GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

->         /auth                securesocial.Routes

my error

[info] Set current project to playMongoDemooo (in build file:/C:/Users/kayjee%20

lahong/demo2/)

[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/kayjee%20lahong/demo2/}playMongoDemooo...

[info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Fin

[info] Done updating.

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 6 Java sources to C:\Users\kayjee lahong\de

mo2\target\scala-2.10\classes...

[error] C:\Users\kayjee lahong\demo2\conf\routes:10: Cannot use a method returni

ng play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result] as an Handler

[error] GET        /current-user        @controllers.Application.currentUser

[error] C:\Users\kayjee lahong\demo2\conf\routes:10: Cannot use a method returni

ng play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result] as an Handler

[error] GET        /current-user        @controllers.Application.currentUser

[error] two errors found

[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

[error] application -

thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Play 2.4 compatibility use 3.0-M4 or newer.  The version you were trying to use does not work with 2.4.